# Qt - I can't select any QListWidget item. They are always auto selected from the top down

Tags: c++, qt

When I go to select A SINGLE item in my QListWidget, it just selects my item, and all of the ones above it. Also, I would like to know how to get a 'right-click context menu' that I can use when I right click the QListWidget. I'll leave an image and my source code. All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

MainWindow:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


QString path;
QStringList before;
QStringList suffixes;
QDir folder;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->checkBoxDateOrdered->setEnabled(false);
    ui->checkBoxInverted->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(false);
    connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), SLOT(showContextMenuForWidget(const QPoint &)));
    ui->listWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showContextMenuForWidget(const QPoint &pos)
{
    QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);
    contextMenu.addAction(new QAction(tr("Hello"), this));
    contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}

void MainWindow::check()
{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    before.clear();
    if (ui->checkBoxDateOrdered->isChecked() && !ui->checkBoxInverted->isChecked())
    {
        before = folder.entryList(QDir::Files, QDir::Time);
    }
    else if (ui->checkBoxInverted->isChecked() && !ui->checkBoxDateOrdered->isChecked())
    {
        before = folder.entryList(QDir::Files, QDir::Reversed);
    }
    else if (ui->checkBoxInverted->isChecked() && ui->checkBoxDateOrdered->isChecked())
    {
        before = folder.entryList(QDir::Files, QDir::Time | QDir::Reversed);
    }
    else
    {
        before = folder.entryList(QDir::Files);
    }
    ui->statusBar->clearMessage();
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString::number(before.size()) + " file(s) found. ");
    ui->listWidget->addItems(before);
    suffixGet();
}

void MainWindow::verify()
{
    before.clear();
    check();
    suffixes.clear();
    suffixGet();
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
    ui->statusBar->clearMessage();
}

void MainWindow::update()
{
    before.clear();
    check();
    if (ui->listWidget->count() == 0 && ui->listWidget_2->count() > 0)
    {
        ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if (ui->listWidget->count() > 0 && ui->listWidget_2->count() == 0)
    {
        ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if (ui->listWidget->count() > 0 && ui->listWidget->count() > 0)
    {
        ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(false);
    }
}

void MainWindow::makeList()
{

    check();
    suffixes.clear();
    suffixGet();
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
    ui->statusBar->clearMessage();
    folder.setPath(path);
    check();
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString::number(before.size()) + " file(s) found. " + " Path: " + path);
}

void MainWindow::suffixGet()
{
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
    QStringList temp;
    QString suffix;
    QString temp2;
    QStringList after;

    for (int x = 0; x < before.size(); x++)
    {
        temp2 = before.at(x);
        temp = temp2.split(".");
        suffix = "." + temp.value(temp.length() - 1);
        suffixes << suffix;
        after << QString::number(x) + suffix;
    }
    ui->listWidget_2->addItems(after);
}

void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    before.clear();
    suffixes.clear();
    suffixGet();
    path.clear();
    path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), "/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);

    if (path != "")
    {
        makeList();
    }
    ui->lineEdit->setText(path);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    before.clear();
    check();
    suffixes.clear();
    suffixGet();
    for (int x = 0; x < before.size(); x++)
    {
        int i = x;
        folder.rename(before.at(x), QString::number(i++) + suffixes.at(x));
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    before.clear();
    suffixes.clear();
    suffixGet();
    check();
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
    if (arg1 == "")
    {
        ui->checkBoxDateOrdered->setEnabled(false);
        ui->checkBoxInverted->setEnabled(false);
        ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
        ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(false);
        ui->statusBar->clearMessage();
    }
    else if (arg1 != "")
    {
        if (QDir(arg1).exists())
        {
            ui->checkBoxDateOrdered->setEnabled(true);
            ui->checkBoxInverted->setEnabled(true);
            ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
            ui->pushButtonClear->setEnabled(true);
            path = arg1;
            makeList();
        }
        else
        {
            ui->statusBar->showMessage("Invalid path!");
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonClear_clicked()
{
    before.clear();
    suffixes.clear();
    suffixGet();
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
    verify();
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMenu>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void check();
    void verify();
    void update();
    void makeList();
    void suffixGet();

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_toolButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_checkBoxDateOrdered_clicked()
    {
        check();
    }

    void on_checkBoxInverted_clicked()
    {
        check();
    }

    void on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

    void on_pushButtonClear_clicked();

    void on_listWidget_currentTextChanged()
    {
        update();
    }

    void on_listWidget_2_currentTextChanged()
    {
        update();
    }

public slots:
    void showContextMenuForWidget(const QPoint &pos);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```